# What is the right way for passing data between 2 child components in svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

What is the right way for me to pass data between 2 child components?
What I have is a pretty straightforward structure:

**APP.svelte**

```
<script>
        import Carmaterial from "./Carmaterial.svelte";
        import Carcolor from "./Carcolor.svelte";

        const carMaterial = {
            title: 'Please select car material',
            property: 'carMaterial',
            options: [
                {id: 0, name: 'Gold'},
                {id: 1, name: 'Titanium'},
                {id: 2, name: 'Silver'}
            ],
        };
    
        const carColor = {
            title: 'Please select car color',
            property: 'carColor',
            options: [
                {id: 0, name: 'Black'},
                {id: 1, name: 'Blue'},
                {id: 2, name: 'Orange'},
                {id: 3, name: 'White'},
                {id: 4, name: 'Yellow'},
                {id: 5, name: 'Green'},
            ],
        };
            
    </script>
    
    //here im passing all of the data to the components itself

    <Carmaterial {...carMaterial} />
    <Carcolor {...carColor}/>
    
    
    <style>
    
    </style>
```

The components are basically 2 sets of radio inputs:

**Carmaterial.svelte**

```
<script>

export let property;
export let title;
export let options;

//im using this in order to predefine value
export let selected = options[1];

</script>
<h3>{title}</h3>
<ul>
{#each options as option (option.id)}

    <li>
        <label>
            <input 
                value={option.id} 
                bind:group={selected.id} 
                type="radio" 
                name={property}>
            {option.name}
        </label>
        
    </li>

{/each}
</ul>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

**Carcolor.svelte**

```
<script>
export let property;
export let title;
export let options;

//im using this in order to predefine value
export let selected = options[2];

</script>
<h3>{title}</h3>
<ul>
{#each options as option (option.id)}

    <li>
        <label>
            <input 
                value={option.id} 
                bind:group={selected.id} 
                type="radio" 
                name={property}>
            {option.name}
        </label>
        
    </li>

{/each}
</ul>
<style lang="scss"></style>
```

in the end my output looks like

```
h3 with Title
ul li with material options
h3 with Title
ul li with color options
```

What im trying to achieve is -> I need somehow to disable "Orange" and "White" radio buttons (from carColor group) when "Titanium" material (from carMaterial group) is selected.

Is this possible without using Shop?
And if yes, what would be the best solution in case I don't want to messed up my data flow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways:

1. use a store, this would provide a 'shared' place for the components to get their data
2. move the data to the parent component and pass it on to the children:

```html
<script>
 let selectedMaterial = 'paper';
 let selectedColor = 'orange';
</script>

<Carmaterial {...carMaterial} {selectedColor} bind:selectedMaterial />
<Carcolor {...carColor} {selectedMaterial} bind:selectedColor />
```

Note that instead of using `selected` I would be using `selectedMaterial` and `selectedColor` in the respective component just to keep it shorter.

The basic principle is easy to understand though: bind the selection from 1 component to the parent, pass this selection to the other component.

You are already keeping the possible data in the parent, this seems like a natural thing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Stephane for your time. Do you think this will stay a valid option if, lets say, carcolor will depend on more then one component (later)? Or if im planning some sort of dependencies expansion I should go with stores?

Comment: That is fully up to you, also strongly depends on what you do with this data, if it send further later on a store might be interesting